# TypeError:Cannot read property 'androidNotificationToken' of undefined exports.onMessageSent.functions.firestore.document.onCreate(/workspace/index.js

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, android-notifications

**EDITED onMessageSent function. Still the same error.**

I'm trying to enable push notifications in flutter and I am using Firebase Messaging. I am encountering the following issue. There are two, namely "onCreateActivityFeedItem" & "onMessageSent".
For the first one, "onCreateActivityFeedItem", the notification feature is perfectly fine, but I could not recognize the problem with the second one. Please do help.

The problem I am facing :

```
onMessageSent
TypeError: Cannot read property 'androidNotificationToken' of undefined at exports.onMessageSent.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:152:47) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Here is the "onCreateActivityFeedItem" :
From my index.js

```
exports.onCreateActivityFeedItem = functions.firestore
  .document("/feed/{userId}/feedItems/{activityFeedItem}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("Activity Feed Item Created", snapshot.data());

    // 1) Get user connected to the feed
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const mediaUrl=context.params.mediaUrl;
    const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userId}`);
    const doc = await userRef.get();

    // 2) Once we have user, check if they have a notification token; send notification, if they have a token
    const androidNotificationToken = doc.data().androidNotificationToken;
    const createdActivityFeedItem = snapshot.data();
    if (androidNotificationToken) {
      sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, createdActivityFeedItem);
    } else {
      console.log("No token for user, cannot send notification");
    }

    function sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, activityFeedItem) {
      let body;

      // 3) switch body value based off of notification type
      switch (activityFeedItem.type) {
        case "comment":
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} replied: ${
            activityFeedItem.commentData
          }.`;
          break;
        case "like":
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} booped you.`;
          break;
        case "follow":
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} started petting you.`;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      // 4) Create message for push notification
      const message = {
        notification: {
         body:body,
         image:mediaUrl
         },
        token: androidNotificationToken,

        data: {recipient: userId,
         }
      };

      // 5) Send message with admin.messaging()
      admin
        .messaging()
        .send(message)
        .then(response => {
          // Response is a message ID string

          console.log("Successfully sent message", response);
          return null;
        })
         .catch(error => {
         console.log("Successfully sent message", response);
         throw Error("Could not send message.",error)});
//         admin.messaging().sendToDevice(androidNotificationToken,message);
    }
  });
```

From my index.js

Here is the, "onMessageSent":

```
exports.onMessageSent = functions.firestore
.document('/messages/{chatId}/messageInfo/{messageFeedItem}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  console.log("Message Created", snapshot.data());

  // 1) Get user connected to the feed
  const chatId=context.params.chatId;
  const userId = context.params.idTo;
  const idTo =context.params.idTo;
  const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${idTo}`);
  const doc = await userRef.get();
  const createdMessageFeedItem = snapshot.data();
      // 2) Once we have user, check if they have a notification token; send notification, if they have a token
  const androidNotificationToken = doc.data().androidNotificationToken;


  if (androidNotificationToken) {
    sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, createdMessageFeedItem);
  } else {
    console.log("No token for user, cannot send notification");
  }

  function sendNotification(androidNotificationToken,createdMessageFeedItem) {
    let body;

    // 3) switch body value based off of notification type
    switch (messageFeedItem.type) {
      case 0:
        body = `${messageFeedItem.username} has sent a message : ${
          messageFeedItem.content
        }.`;
        break;
      case 1:
        body = `${messageFeedItem.username} has sent an image.`;
        break;
      case 2:
        body = `${messageFeedItem.username} has sent a gif.`;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    // 4) Create message for push notification
    const message = {
      notification:
      {body:body,},
      token: androidNotificationToken,
      data: {recipient: idTo,}
    };

    // 5) Send message with admin.messaging()
    admin
      .messaging()
      .send(androidNotificationToken,message)
      .then(response => {
        // Response is a message ID string
        console.log("Successfully sent message", response);
        return null;
      })
       .catch(error => {
       console.log("Successfully sent message", response);
       throw Error("Could not send message.",error)});
//         admin.messaging().sendToDevice(androidNotificationToken,message);
  }
});
```

Where I called/declared the onMessage, onResume :

```
configurePushNotifications() {
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      getiOSPermission();
    }
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print("Firebase messaging token : $token");
      setState(() {
        currentUser.androidNotificationToken = token;
      });
      usersref.doc(user.id).update({"androidNotificationToken": token});
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
          print("Firebase messaging token : $token");
          usersref.doc(user.id).update({"androidNotificationToken": token});
        });
//        print("On Launch : $message\n");
//        _navigateToDetail(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
          print("Firebase messaging token : $token");
          usersref.doc(user.id).update({"androidNotificationToken": token});
        });
        print("On Resume : $message");
        _navigateToDetail(message);
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("On message : $message\n");
        final String recipientId = message['data']['recipient'];
        final String body = message['notification']['body'];
        if (recipientId == user.id) {
          //Notification shown");
          SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            content: Text(
              body,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            action: SnackBarAction(
                label: "Go",
                textColor: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                      return ActivityFeed();
                    }),
                  );
                }),
          );
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
        //Notifications not shown.");
      },
    );
  }
```

I tried different ways like getting the androidNotificationToken by updating in cloud firestore and getting it, but it didn't work.
[Users in Cloud Firestore][1]
[1] https://imgur.com/a/u5Df0zD

I'm just a beginner, trying to learn new stuff. Please do help.
Thank you,
SLN

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not show pictures of text and code.  Copy only the relevant code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Doug Stevenson

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot read type error of undefined` 
error happens when the data dosent exist at `docu.data().androidNotificationToken`

Ensure the reference is correct, I prefer using this type of path for more clarity
`let ref = db.collection(‘users’).doc(userID);`etc

You can also catch a empty snapshot

```
var snapshot = await ref.get();
if(snapshot.empty){
 console.log(‘snapshot is empty’);
}
```

Comment: Error : Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

. 
Tried : let ref =  admin.firestore().collection(`users`).doc(userId);
            const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userId}`);





What could possibly go wrong..

Comment: This new error you get is when a value in the ref is null